# how to create the stored proc with parameter in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to Create a stored procedure for top 25 students by year. 
        SO the Proc should take year as param and return, student id, 
        sum of marks for the year

```
Alter  PROCEDURE getstudents
(  
@year INT
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT student-name FROM tbl_Students WHERE year=@year
Thanks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getstudents

      @year INT

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 25
            student_name
          , student_id
          , marks = SUM(marks)
    FROM dbo.tbl_Students 
    WHERE [Year] = @year
     GROUP BY 
            student_name
          , student_id
     ORDER BY marks DESC

END
```

Or this -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getstudents

      @year INT
    , @count INT

AS
BEGIN

     SELECT student_name, student_id, marks
     FROM (
         SELECT 
                 student_name
               , student_id
               , marks
               , rn = ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY marks DESC) 
         FROM (
             SELECT 
                      student_name
                    , student_id
                    , marks = SUM(marks)
             FROM dbo.tbl_Students 
             WHERE [Year] = @year
               GROUP BY 
                      student_name
                    , student_id
         ) t
     ) t2
    WHERE t2.rn <= @count

END
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a crystal ball. Please provide a `DDL` for your table.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE getstudents

      @year INT

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 25 [student-name]
    FROM tbl_Students WHERE year=@year

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You've passed parameter in the right way.

Now you must cange your query inside SP about information you want.

So the final select show the result you have extracted.

Obviously about dealer student, student i and so on, you write here your db model.